# how to install flash stream hunter_1.0.10.exe in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: sound, streaming

I am new in linux operating system, please inform me how to install Flash Stream Hunter software in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Can you provide links to what this software is? and if its a windows software you're talking of, we'll gladly suggest linux equivalents or help you install it in wine.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it is a streaming video download service. Minitube can view and download Youtube videos, and it is in the Software Center.